# Can't figure out how to center image with margin: auto

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

I've checked multiple threads and have tried multiple options. I've tried setting display to block, setting specific width for both image and container. Any other condition that I might be missing out on?

**HTML:**

```
<footer>
    <div id="footercontent">
        <div id="logobox">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />   <--- THIS IS THE IMAGE IN QUESTION
        </div>
        <div id="social">

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
#footercontent {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
}
#logobox {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
}
img {
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
#social {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` and apply `margin: 0 auto` to `img`. When `position: absolute` is applied on some element, it is taken out from the normal flow of DOM

```
img {
    height: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```